# Pass an @Output to Angular App Shell from Micro Ui

Tags: angular, micro-frontend

Micro UI

Where the output event is emitted.

```
  @Output
  public actionCompleted: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public optionsActionComplete(result: ActionCompletedResult): void {
    this.loadOrderItemsWithMappedNames();
    this.actionCompleted.emit('true');
  }
```

Shell

How the output event is consumed.

```
<app-view-order (actionCompleted)="actionCompleted($event)"></app-view-order>

public actionCompleted(result: string): void {
    console.log('refresh basket');
    this.basket.nativeElement.refresh = true;
  }
```

Can anyone let me know why this is not working for Angular Shell? I have successfully passed @Input fro Shell to a component before.

Answer (score 0):

U have to decorate [@Output()](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) on EventEmitter if u want to receive event on parent

```
@Output() 
 public actionCompleted: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Comment: I forgot to put it in the question..@Output is there